# java.lang.IllegalStateException while closing popup form using OC4J 10.1.3.5 and ADF

Tags: java, oc4j, oracle-adf

We are using OC4J 10.1.3.5 and ADF.  I have a popup form and when closing we got error below. I wonder what am I missing and how can I resolve it?

```
Jun 15, 2010 8:26:49 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase execute
SEVERE: java.lang.IllegalStateException: popView(): No view has been pushed.
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: popView(): No view has been pushed.
        at com.sun.faces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:150)
        at oracle.adf.view.faces.component.UIXComponentBase.__broadcast(UIXComponentBase.java:1087)
        at oracle.adf.view.faces.component.UIXCommand.broadcast(UIXCommand.java:204)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:269)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:327)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:99)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:245)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:110)
        at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:213)
        at com.evermind.server.http.ResourceFilterChain.doFilter(ResourceFilterChain.java:64)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.AdfFacesFilterImpl._invokeDoFilter(AdfFacesFilterImpl.java:233)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.AdfFacesFilterImpl._doFilterImpl(AdfFacesFilterImpl.java:202)
        at oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.AdfFacesFilterImpl.doFilter(AdfFacesFilterImpl.java:12
```

Comment: This may be helpful: http://www.google.com/search?q="No+view+has+been+pushed"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> [`IllegalStateException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

There's no silver bullet to resolve these kinds of exceptions; you have to deal with it on a case by case basis, studying the API of whatever library you're using, and figuring out where the illegal state happens.

In this particular case, it looks like `popView()` is being called when the stack is empty. You may be missing a `pushView`, or miscalculating the number of pushes vs pops.